# didSet does not fire on @Published property when assign(to:) is used

Tags: swift, swiftui, combine

The didSet observer does not fire when the value is changed due to the assignment. Is this a bug or a feature?

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var v = vm()
    var body: some View {
        Text(String(v.b))
            .padding()
    }
}

class vm: ObservableObject {
    @Published var b = false {
        didSet {
            print("hello didSet \(b)")
        }
    }
    
    let pub = CurrentValueSubject<Bool, Never>(false)
    
    init() {
        b = true
        pub.assign(to: &$b)
        pub.send(true)
        pub.send(false)
    }
}
```

Expected output:

> hello didSet true
>
> hello didSet false
>
> hello didSet true
>
> hello didSet false

Actual output:

> hello didSet true

Assigning the value with `.sink()` is a workaround but why doesn't `assign(to:)` trigger the `didSet` observer?

Comment: That's not the same question at all.

Comment: Instead of assigning to published internal storage, assign by key path, like `pub.assign(to: \.b, on: self)` - it solves your case. But... in any case it brings cross-reference, so `sink` is preferable, because allows `weak self`.